# Matrix plot: unable to style rotated column names

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, matrix

What I want to do is create a Matrix where each is clickable, and javascript gives me elements clicked.
I have this HTML
`<table id="availability">
    <tr>
        <th class="lat-header rotate"></th>
        <th class="rotate">Mattino</th>
        <th class="rotate">Pomeriggio</th>
        <th class="rotate">Sera</th>
        <th class="rotate">Full-time</th>
    </tr>
    <tr id="day_[0]">
        <th class="lat-header">Lun</th>
        <td data-role="00"></td>
        <td data-role="01"></td>
        <td data-role="02"></td>
        <td data-role="03"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="day_[1]">
        <th class="lat-header">Mar</th>
        <td data-role="10"></td>
        <td data-role="11"></td>
        <td data-role="12"></td>
        <td data-role="13"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="day_[2]">
        <th class="lat-header">Mer</th>
        <td data-role="20"></td>
        <td data-role="21"></td>
        <td data-role="22"></td>
        <td data-role="23"></td>
    </tr>
</table>`

Then this CSS:

```
table#availability {
    text-align:center;
    width:100%;
}
table#availability th, table#availability td {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 16%;
    height: 4em;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 5px;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height:4em;
}
table#availability td {
    background-color: aqua;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: background-color ease 0.5s
}
table#availability td.cellSelected {
    background-color:#00ff00;
}
table#availability th.lat-header {
    width: 2em;
    text-align: right;
    position:relative;
    left:-1em;
}
table#availability th.rotate {
    /* Safari */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    /* Firefox */
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    /* IE */
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    /* Opera */
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    /* Internet Explorer */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
    text-align:left;
}
```

and last this little javascript:

```
var availMatrixArr = [];//array of clicked elements
jQuery('table#availability td').click(function(){
    var selElIndex = $(this).attr('data-role');
    var indexInArr = jQuery.inArray(selElIndex,availMatrixArr);
    if(indexInArr > -1){
        $(this).removeClass('cellSelected');
        availMatrixArr.splice(indexInArr,1);
    } else {
        availMatrixArr.push(selElIndex);
        $(this).addClass('cellSelected');
    }
    console.log(selElIndex);
    console.log(availMatrixArr);
});
```

The problem is that column headers, which I want aligned to the bottom change their position relative to the table when the screen is resized, so I can get my code work for every screen dimension.
This is my [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ciroxxx/88dubcx2/2/).
If you try to resize the "result" square in the fiddle you will understand what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to edit your html like this:

```
  <tr>
    <th class="lat-header rotate"></th>
    <th><span class='rotate'>Mattino</span></th>
    <th><span class="rotate">Pomeriggio</span></th>
    <th><span class='rotate'>Sera</span>
    <th class="rotate"><span class='rotate'>Fulltime</span>
</tr>
```

and change your css like this

```
table#availability th .rotate {
    display:inline-block;
    width:60px;
    /* Safari */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    /* Firefox */
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    /* IE */
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    /* Opera */
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    /* Internet Explorer */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
    text-align:left;

}
```

Here you can see a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/88dubcx2/4/)